# Understanding independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

If $X,Y$ are two random variables then I understand that $X,Y$ are independent if $P(X=x|Y=y)=P(X=x)$.

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a sequence of random variables. Let $T$ be another random variable.

> I am trying to understand what the statement $X_T$ is independent of $T$ means?

If I again use the definition in the first line then should I say $P(X_T=x|T=t)=P(X_t=x|T=t)=P(X_t=x)$? But that means $P(X_{t}=x)$ is the same for all $t$ i.e. $X_t$ are identically distributed which is not an assumption I started with. I'm missing something simple definition wise.

Comment: Do you mean to write the distribution function $P(X\leq x)$ rather than $P(X=x)$? (the latter could be 0 a.e.)

Comment: @dmh True, I should have the distribution function for real valued $X$, I was thinking of discrete valued $X$ with a finite support.

Comment: It should be $P(X_t=x\mid T=t)=P(X_T=x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying $T$ and $X_T$ are independent means exactly what you said, at least in the case where $X_t$ and $T$ are discrete. It means$P(X_T=x\mid T=t)=P(X_T=x)$, for all $x,t\in \mathbb N$.

I do not see why you think this is a problem. On the one hand, when $t=1$, you get
$$
P(X_1=x\mid T=1)=P(X_T=x\mid T=1)=P(X_T=x)
$$
On the other hand, when $t=2$, you get
$$
P(X_2=x\mid T=2)=P(X_T=x\mid T=2)=P(X_T=x)
$$
But there is no way to leverage those equations to conclude $P(X_1=x)=P(X_2=x)$, so there is no way to conclude $X_1$ and $X_2$ are equidistributed. If you have a line of reasoning which claims otherwise, you should include it in your question, so I can point out exactly where you made your logical error.

I know you must be wrong, because you can concoct stochastic processes $X_t$ and random variables $T$ for which $X_T$ is independent of $T$, but $X_t$ are not identically distributed. For example, let $X_t$ be a simple random walk, equal to $\sum_{i=1}^t \xi_i$, where each $\xi_i$ is independently $\pm 1$ with equal probability, and let $T$ be the first time that the random walk hits $+5$. Then $X_T=5$, so $X_T$ is constant and therefore independent of $T$, but the $X_t$ are clearly not identically distributed.